Data Inconsistency and Improper Transaction Handling in GridDB
I'm building a financial system that stores transaction data in GridDB, when I try to process multiple transactions concurrently over the same account ends up returning an inconsistent final account balance.
I tried processing transactions for the same account using multiple threads. I expected the final balance to show all the transactions correctly, but what I got is something inconsistent and does not show the value I was expecting.
Below is my code
import griddb_python as griddb
import threading

def processTransactions(container, accountId, transactions):
    for amount in transactions:
        query = container.query(f"SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE account_id = {accountId}")
        rs = query.fetch(False)
        
        if rs.has_next():
            currentBalance = rs.next()[0]
            newBalance = currentBalance + amount
            
            updateQuery = container.query(f"UPDATE accounts SET balance = {newBalance} WHERE account_id = {accountId}")
            updateQuery.fetch(False)
        else:
            print(f"Account {accountId} not found.")

try:
    factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
    gridStore = factory.get_store(
        notification_member="127.0.0.1:10001",
        cluster_name="myCluster",
        username="admin",
        password="admin"
    )
    containerInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("accounts",
                                          [["accountId", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                                           ["balance", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]],
                                          griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)
    
    container = gridStore.put_container(containerInfo)
    
    accounts = [
        (1, 1000.0),
        (2, 1500.0),
    ]
    
    for account in accounts:
        container.put(account)
    
    print("Initial data inserted successfully.")
    
    # transactions to be processed 
    transactions1 = [200, -100, 300]
    transactions2 = [-150, 500, -250]
    
    # threads for processing transactions
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=processTransactions, args=(container, 1, transactions1))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=processTransactions, args=(container, 1, transactions2))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    
    query = container.query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accountId = 1")
    rs = query.fetch(False)
    
    while rs.has_next():
        data = rs.next()
        print(f"Final balance for account 1: {data}")
    
except griddb.GSException as e:
    for i in range(e.get_error_stack_size()):
        print("[", i, "]")
        print(e.get_error_code(i))
        print(e.get_location(i))
        print(e.get_message(i))

